# Create a Snapshot of a Raspberry Pi to safe its current state

Tags: raspberry-pi, backup, raspbian, snapshot, omxplayer

On my raspberry pi there is currently running a program that is automatically looping videos using the omxplayer https://github.com/popcornmix/omxplayer/ as soon as the pi finished booting.

Now i encounter one problem:

In case of a power outage the raspberry will start the video from its beginning.
I want the raspberry to start the video exactly where it stopped, after it got power again after a power outage.

**Now my question:**

Can i create a snapshot of the raspberry pi every minute, to safe its complete current state?
In case of a power outage i want the raspberry to boot from the latest snapshot, so it will continue the video where it stopped.

**Is this going to work? If yes, which programs can i use for that?**